# How to get submitted values on $formstate['values'] instead of $formstate['input']?

Tags: 7, forms

I was generating a simple form with below fields, but i am wandering why my field values are not storing in the $formstate['values'], but its in the $formstate['input'].. please have look into below code and correct me if i am doing something wrong.

```
function create_entry_form($form, &$form_state){
    $form['entry']['password'] = array(
      '#type' => 'password',
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#default_value' => '',
      '#maxlength' => 15,
    );

    $form['entry']['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('OK'),
      '#weight' => 100,
    );
    $form['entry']['emailid'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#default_value' => '',
      '#maxlength' => 25,
    );

    $form['entry']['reqbtn'] = array(
      '#type' => 'button',
      '#value' => t('Request'),
      '#weight' => 106,
      '#executes_submit_callback' => TRUE,
      '#submit' => array('request_site_password'),
      '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
    );

  return $form;  
}
function request_site_password($form, &$form_state) {
    echo '<pre>';print_r($form_state);exit;
  }
```

Comment: just curious, it appears you are building a custom password retrieval... why not use Drupal's and why use a custom submit function rather than Drupal's built in submit handler (which would have been create_entry_form_submit)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get $formstate['values'] or $form_state['input'] values .You have to write like below.

```
    function create_entry_form($form, &$form_state){
        $form['entry']['password'] = array(
          '#type' => 'password',
          '#required' => TRUE,
          '#default_value' => '',
          '#maxlength' => 15,
        );

        $form['entry']['submit'] = array(
          '#type' => 'submit',
          '#value' => t('OK'),
          '#weight' => 100,
        );
        $form['entry']['emailid'] = array(
          '#type' => 'textfield',
          '#required' => TRUE,
          '#default_value' => '',
          '#maxlength' => 25,
        );

        $form['entry']['reqbtn'] = array(
          '#type' => 'submit',
          '#value' => t('Request'),
          '#weight' => 106,
          '#submit' => array('request_site_password'),
          );



      return $form;  
    }
   function request_site_password(&$form, &$form_state) {
    drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($form_state['input'], TRUE) . '</pre>');
  }
```

You missed '&$form' in this function request_site_password(&$form, &$form_state)

Comment: The question is about why the values are empty but the input is not, not how to get it.

Comment: I have changed the code based on your comment now you can get the values